# Blank space on SharePoint development environment

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, development-enviroment

I am developing a webpart for SharePoint and I have an annoying issue with my development environment for sharepoint Online. I have a blank space on the right. How can I fix it ? It's an unusable space that I cant' remove which it's present even when I generate a new project. I can't add webpart on it. And some webpart seems to pass under it.
I make my webpart using ReactJS and the Office UI Fabric.

I already tried to reinstall but I still have the same issue.

I use IE11.

Could you help me ?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Fabric } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Fabric';
import styles from './Graph.module.scss';
import { IGraphProps } from './IGraphProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';


import {
  Image,
  IImageProps,
  ImageFit
} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Image';

export default class Graph extends React.Component<IGraphProps, {}> {
  public render() {
    const imageProps: IImageProps = {
      imageFit: ImageFit.contain
    };

    return (
      <div className={styles.testdiv}>
        <h1>Test d'image</h1>
        <Fabric>
          <Image {...imageProps as any} src="http://placehold.it/600x300" className={styles.test} alt="Example implementation of the property image fit using the contain value on an image wider than the frame." width={400} height={200} />
        </Fabric>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Blank space on sharepoint development environment]

I should have that :
[image]

And I have that :
[image]

The space for the webpart doesn't take the full page, but it should be.

Comment: can you share some code ? Are you using the property pane correctly ?

Comment: I didn't code anything yet for the pane property. I have this issue even with a blank projet and the default sharepoint component. I had my code.

Comment: I try to add more explanations. If I am not clear enough could you tell on what point please.

Comment: Could you try to remove the ' from your code? This starts is a multiline string.

Comment: @Oskar Sorry, I am not sure to understand. I don't see where I have to remove the ' .

Comment: `<h1>Test d'image</h1>
        <Fabric>
          <Image {...imageProps as any} src="http://placehold.it/600x300" className={styles.test} alt='Example implementation of the property image fit using the contain value on an image wider than the frame.' width={400} height={200} />
        </Fabric>
      </div>` **behind**  `Test d` **and** `alt=` **and** `than the frame.`

Comment: Thank you, but my issue is still there.

Comment: Anyone to help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is default `IE11` behaivor of `workbench` page. `Edge`, `Chrome` displays it in the corerct way. 
When you put webpart in the real page the width will changes automatically.

The issue that it is not allowed to use different page layouts in the `workbench` except the bilt-in. 
According to `SPFx` roadmap `workbench 2.0` is comming soon, I hope they will extend the functionality of it.

As workaround you can use mobile/tablet view.